# Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: django, python-2.7, rabbitmq, celery

I am using RabbitMQ server with Django 1.8 on CentOS. When I restart the rabbitmq-server, the operation completes and shows the message "restart ok". But when I see the status it shows following output:

```
Starting node rabbit@bynrySystem ...
Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@bynrySystem: nodedown

DAIGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: [rabbit@bynrySystem]

rabbit@bynrySystem:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on bynrySystem
  * epmd reports: node 'rabbit' not running at all
                  no other nodes on bynrySystem
  * suggestion: start the node

current node details:
- node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-59@bynrySystem'
- home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
- cookie hash: f/MoFCCKTONVCYhIDLxvew==

When I run a task it gives following error.

consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
```

Answer (score 0):

A common cause for this error is that the cookie hash is incorrectly set after a shutdown. If you don't have any valuable data or definitions in your RabbitMQ node, just stop the service and remove /var/lib/rabbitmq/*, then start it back.

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/rabbitmq/*
```

This **resets** the node, so it deletes all messages.

Comment: will it delete all the message present in the exchange?

Comment: @ANDY_VAR **YES** (messages are in queues though, not "in" the exchange)

Comment: Did not work for me. My configuration had been working, and not sure what caused it to stop working. With this proposed fix, I am still seeing .[2019-11-12 22:36:27,102: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
Trying again in 8.00 seconds... and 16 sec... etc

Comment: @zerocog you error might be just that the server is not running and unrelated to OPs issue.

Comment: The error was because my libcrypto version did not match after an update. I re-installed, and then the libcrypto was correct, and rabbitmqctl worked again. If what I did fully works then I may add an answer to re-install rabbit to get the  openssl sync'd.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was the rabbitmqctl reset

```
rabbitmqctl stop_app
rabbitmqctl reset
rabbitmqctl start_app
rabbitmqctl list_users
```

resulted in

```
Listing users ...
guest   [administrator]
```

ref [enter link description here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmqctl.8.html#reset)

This will work for the default configuration. However, seems a better practice to create a vhost with user with permissions to access that vhost.